# <Spring Batch> Why does making ItemReader thread-safe leads us to loosing restartability?

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I have a multi-threaded batch job reading from a DB and I am concerned about different threads re-reading records as ItemReader is not thread safe in Spring batch. I went through [SpringBatch FAQ](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/faq.html) section which states that

> You can synchronize the read() method (e.g. by wrapping it in a delegator that does the synchronization). Remember that you will lose restartability, so best practice is to mark the step as not restartable and to be safe (and efficient) you can also set saveState=false on the reader.

I want to know why will I loose re-startability in this case? What has restartability got to do with synchronizing my read operations? It can always try again,right?
Also, will this piece of code be enough for synchronizing the reader?

```
  public SynchronizedItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<T> {
  private final ItemReader<T> delegate; 
  public SynchronizedItemReader(ItemReader<T> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }
  public synchronized T read () {
    return delegate.read();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should look at the Partitioning functionality of Spring Batch: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html (See section 7.4). The idea is to split your records into partitions ahead of time and have the reader only operate on a single partition, that way you can be sure no two readers will re-read the same record. It also allows re-startability.

Comment: here is the [SpringBatch FAQ](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/faq.html#threading-reader) new location (the one above is broken)

Answer (score 6):

When using an ItemReader with multithreads, the lack of restartability is not about the read itself.  It's about saving the state of the reader which occurs in the update method.  The issue is that there needs to be coordination between the calls to read() - the method providing the data and update() - the method persisting the state.  When you use multiple threads, the internal state of the reader (and therefore the update() call) may or may not reflect the work that has been done.  Take for example the FlatFileItemReader using a chunk size of 5 and running on multiple threads.  You could have thread1 having read 5 items (time to update), yet thread 2 could have read an additional 3.  This means that the call to update would save that 8 items have been read.  If the chunk on thread 2 fails, the state would due incorrect and the restart would miss the three items that were already read.

This is not to say that it is impossible to write a thread safe ItemReader.  However, as your example above illustrates, if delegate is a stateful ItemReader (implements ItemStream as well), the state will not be persisted correctly with calls to update (in fact, your example above doesn't even take the ItemStream aspect of stageful readers into account).

Comment: Can you please provide a pseudo-example to write a thread-safe itemReader?

Comment: In order for a ItemReader to be thread safe, the state of the reader must also be thread safe.  This leaves you with two options: synchronizing the state or using something like a ThreadLocal and aggregating the state when update is called.  In either case, there are many dependencies on what the underlying data structure you are reading can do as well as how the state can be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want make restartable your job, with parallel execution of items, you can save item, that reader read plus state of this item by yourself.